# Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified; Selenium webdriver options have no effect

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I'm running this on arm64 ubuntu 20.04 lts with python3-selenium installed. After specifying --headless arguments and running this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
serv = Service("/usr/local/bin/firefox/geckodriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, firefox_options=opt)
driver.get(site)
```

I still get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Some further digging into the geckodriver.log file

```
mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilewMNmVf"
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

Oddly enough, none of the arguments I specified are is being run here. Any ideas?

Using the exact same code with webdriver.Chrome instead of webdriver.Firefox works. Unfortunately, I need this to work with firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently you're supposed to set

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=opt)
```

NOT

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, firefox_options=opt)
```

Oddly enough, both parameters are available in webdriver.Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
serv = Service("/usr/local/bin/firefox/geckodriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=opt)
driver.get(site)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox to be headless:

```
opt.headless = True
```

or

```
opt.set_headless()
```

Comment: ```opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.headless = True
serv = Service(executable_path="/usr/bin/geckodriver", log_path=None)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, firefox_options=opt)
driver.get(site)
```
Unfortunately that doesn't work either: 
```mozrunner::runner INFO Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilel0dYhx"```